# chapterthumb table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, chapterthumb

Is there is now an easy way to create a *chapterthumb table of contents*?

To concretize: I think with a very dezent type like

[image]

I think a chapterthumb table of contents is not trivial because it has to be dimensionally the same as the margins:

[image]

The chapterthumbs themselves should be dezent too, for example

[image]

with the one difference that just in the black box (in white) '1,2,3, ...' stands for the chapters 1,2,3, ... etc. or an 'I' for table of contents or 'A, B, C, ...' for  attachment A, B, C, ....

`chapterthumbexample.tex`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{chapterthumb}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{chapterthumb}
\addtokomafont{chapterthumb}{\bfseries}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}\dots
\chapter{Second Chapter}\dots
\chapter{Some Title}\dots
\chapter{and so on}\dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice your question.